# Elasticsearch swapping on windows server 2008 r2

Tags: elasticsearch

I have disabled swapping:

```
bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

Disabled paging file, rebooted.

ES is still swapping, 9GB and growing.

21% of heap size is used.

Same issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/720899/why-does-elasticsearch-reports-swapping-when-swapping-is-disabled

Comment: What's the value of `mlockall` in the response from `curl http://localhost:9200/_nodes/process?pretty`?

Comment: @ejain process: {
refresh_interval_in_millis: 1000,
id: 4972,
mlockall: true
}

Comment: ES eats memory up to 100% when going through all the records "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            }, or when doing bulk operations. - Same index and config  works fine on linux.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, Elasticsearch uses the *VirtualLock* function, which, according to [this source](https://web.archive.org/web/20190212234155/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071106-00/?p=24573/), does not completely prevent swapping.

Comment: Worth mentioning the same Author issued a somewhat relevant correction here:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140207-00/?p=1833 

"When you lock memory with Virtual­Lock, it will remain locked even if all your threads are blocked. (...) Virtually-locked pages were never unlocked in practice."